# ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'hydra-development': Could not create a new core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I am trying to run `solr_wrapper` along with `fc_wrapper` to run my app.

This is how I am starting the solr,

```
enter code here

solr_wrapper -d solr/config/ --collection_name hydra-development --version 6.3.0
```

But when I hit this command, below is the error I am getting.

> Failed to execute solr create:  (RuntimeError)
>   Creating new core 'hydra-development' using command:
>
> http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=hydra-development&instanceDir=hydra-development

I am able to start the fc_wrapper.

Can someone helpstarting the solr_wrapper.

Comment: Does the URL work just in your browser?

Comment: It doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

These "solr_wrapper" and "fc_wrapper" tools do not come with Solr.  Somebody else built those, so I have no idea how they work or what they do.

In order to create a core, the config must be available.  See the big red box here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE